# django model user create index for first_name, last_name

Tags: django, django-models

I use `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` as default user model

And I want to create index on

```
public.auth_user.first_name
public.auth_user.last_name
```

Are there any elegant way to create this indexes ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by specifying a different `User` model. By simply inheriting from the [**`AbstractUser`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.AbstractUser) and specifying the indexes:

```
# app_name/models.py

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=150, db_index=True, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=150, db_index=True, blank=True)
    
    class Meta(AbstractUser.Meta):
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
```

then you can specify the user model to refer to the `User` model in the *`app_name`* module:

```
# settings.py

# ⋮

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'app_name.User'

# ⋮
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit ugly but still elegant way: Create raw SQL migration witch create index.

First

```
pip3 install django-migrate-sql-deux
```

Then

```
import migrate_sql.operations

from django.conf import settings
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('my_app', '0094_last_migration_name')
    ]
    operations = [
        migrate_sql.operations.CreateSQL(
            name='auth_user_first_name_idx',
            sql='create index auth_user_first_name_idx on auth_user (first_name)',
            reverse_sql='drop index auth_user_first_name_idx',
        ),
        migrate_sql.operations.CreateSQL(
            name='auth_user_last_name_idx',
            sql='create index auth_user_last_name_idx on auth_user (last_name)',
            reverse_sql='drop index auth_user_last_name_idx',
        ),
    ]
```